# color changed based on clicks on that button in android

Tags: android, button

I have made a very simple program for button color change based on clicks on that button.I have tried the code as below which is not working.Please help me for the same,My code is as below:

**main.java**

```
package com.example.buttonclickdemo;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {
Button b;
int cnt;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        b=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);
        b.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            cnt++;

            }
        });
        if(cnt<5)
        {
            b.setBackgroundColor(16711681);
        }
        else if (cnt>5 && cnt<10) {
            b.setBackgroundColor(16711936);
        }
        else{
            b.setBackgroundColor(65536);
        }
    }



}
```

Comment: your `b.setBackgroundColor(65536);` should be inside onClick of Button..

Comment: @CRUSADER all his logic should be inside tht onClick

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to put your logic into the `onClick()` method. Currently it's just in `onCreate()`, which only gets called once.

```
b.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            cnt++;
            if(cnt<5) {
                b.setBackgroundColor(16711681);
            }
            else if (cnt>5 && cnt<10) {
                b.setBackgroundColor(16711936);
            }
            else {
                b.setBackgroundColor(65536);
            }
        }
    });
```

Comment: :) Hehehe we have too much time on our hands obviously

Comment: @KenWolf-hehe...watta coincidence..:)

Comment: @Carnal-yeap bro..watta timing..:)

Answer (score 2):

in your code the button color change (the if condition) is inside the on create method so it will be invoked only when activity is loaded instead change it to inside on click method so it can be checked on each click

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        b=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);
        b.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            cnt++;
  if(cnt<5)
        {
            b.setBackgroundColor(16711681);
        }
        else if (cnt>5 && cnt<10) {
            b.setBackgroundColor(16711936);
        }
        else{
            b.setBackgroundColor(65536);
        }

            }
        });

    }
```

Answer (score 1):

```
b.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        cnt++;

        if(cnt<5)
    {
        b.setBackgroundColor(16711681);
    }
    else if (cnt>5 && cnt<10) {
        b.setBackgroundColor(16711936);
    }
    else{
        b.setBackgroundColor(65536);
    }
        }
    });
```

You need to set the if conditions inside your `OnClickListener`. Because `onCreate` will only be called once when the `Activity` is created, therefor it will only do that once.

Comment: Thanks for your help bro..:) have a nyc day.!

Comment: Any time bro ;) have a nice one!

Answer (score 1):

Move this

```
 if(cnt<5)
        {
            b.setBackgroundColor(16711681);
        }
        else if (cnt>5 && cnt<10) {
            b.setBackgroundColor(16711936);
        }
        else{
            b.setBackgroundColor(65536);
        }
```

to the `onClick` listener. 
The onClick call back is invoked only after the event takes place and the rest of the code you have written has already been called, and hence the colours dont change.

Better yet define custom xml's

Comment: Thanx fro helping...! brothr..!

Answer (score 1):

I have solved it my way by following code:

```
        b.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            cnt++;

            if(cnt<5)
        {
            b.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#d4cae2"));
        }
        else if (cnt>5 && cnt<10) {
            b.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#00cbcc"));
        }
        else{
            b.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#d1bff0"));
        }
            }
        });
}
}
```